# Changing country name (Ireland to be Republic of Ireland) in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, country-regions, translate

I need to change Ireland to the Republic of Ireland. No matter what I change and clear the caches it does not update

I have tried editing

vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/Translation.php
vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

Along with adding Ireland to the the en_GB.csv in my il8n file

Could anyone else advise

Comment: Can you try with static content deploy command.